# Grouped Bar Plot in R with categorical data

Tags: r, bar-chart

My data is as follows

```
Q1                   Q2                  Q3                   Q4    
Strongly Agree       Strongly Agree      Agree                Agree
Agree                Strongly Agree      Agree                Strongly Agree
Strongly Agree       Disagree            Strongly Disagree    Disagree
Disagree             Agree               Strongly Agree       Agree
Agree                Agree               Disagree             Disagree
Strongly Disagree    Strongly Disagree   Disagree             Disagree
```

I want to make a grouped bar plot that has the frequency as the height. The groups along the bottom of the graph are the 'strongly agree', 'agree', 'disagree' and 'strongly disagree'. Then in each group there will be the different questions.

This is what I have so far:

```
Question <- c(df$`Q24#1_4`, df$`Q24#1_1`, df$`Q24#1_2`, df$`Q24#1_3`)
ggplot(Question, aes(x = c('Strongly Disagree', 'Disagree', 'Agree', 
                           'Sgrongly Agree'))) + geom_bar()
```

Comment: You should [tidy](http://garrettgman.github.io/tidying/) your data first with `tidyr::gather(df)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to fix your data before plotting (you can use `melt` for that .There are many different ways to do this)

(1). You can create an `id` column (i.e with `rownames`) to melt your data

`data$id<-rownames(data)`

(2). Now, you can melt your data using that new column

`library(reshape)`

`data_melt<-melt(data, id="id")`

(3). The data is ready for plotting ...

`ggplot(data_melt,aes(factor(value)))+geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), position = "dodge")`

[image]